# SCSS - Mixins - Pass different value to a single css property

Tags: vue.js, sass, mixins

I want to do a text mixin, but idk how to pass optional properties to the font-family.
In this example, it takes two values (if the first one is not supported by the browser it will use the second one)

This wont work: `$fontFamily: "Montserrat SemiBold" | sans-serif`

```
@mixin text($fontSize: 20px, $fontFamily: "Montserrat SemiBold" | sans-serif, ...) {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Montserrat SemiBold", sans-serif;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses:

```css
@mixin text(
    $fontSize: 20px,
    $fontFamily: ('Montserrat SemiBold', sans-serif)
) {
    font-size: $fontSize;
    font-family: $fontFamily;
}
```